# getTime JS code is not working correctly

Tags: javascript

What I am trying to do is display a default string, and when a certain time is reached it has to update that string. The string will be updated in the h1 that has css behind it.

This is my code:

```
<h1  id="header" class="loginhead" ></h1> 
    <script>
        //pu8t in onload
        document.onload = setDateChange();

        function setDateChange(){
            // datestring format yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss
            String output ="Welcome to the All-Stars Summit Registration Site, Canada";
            if (Date().getTime() > Date("2015-07-15 23:59:00").getTime())
                {
                    output ="The All-Stars Summit Registration Site, Canada, is now closed";
                }
        document.getElementById('header').innerHTML = output; //change the html/text inside of the span with the id closed'.
        }

    setDateChange();

    //figure out which date is next
    //*********************
    var timeTillNextDate = Date("2015-07-15 23:59:00").getTime();
    var timeTillRun = Date("2015-07-15 23:59:00").getTime() - Date().getTime();
    if(timeTillRun > 0){
        setTimeout(setDateChange()), timeTillNextDate); //will wait to call changeHeader function until timeTillChange milliseconds have occured.
    }
    </script>
```

The JsFiddle link is here: [JSFiddle Code](http://jsfiddle.net/mh2q7c16/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do some modifications to fix the error

1. change `Date()` to `new Date()` wherever it is used.
2. Remove the extra parentheses. Modify

`setTimeout(setDateChange()),timeTillNextDate);`

**to**

`setTimeout(setDateChange(),timeTillNextDate);`

3. `String` is not a datatype in JS. So, change it to `var`

`String output` **to** `var output`

Answer (score 1):

Replace `Date()` with `(new Date())` as @PraveenKumar has suggested.

Along with that you have a syntax error here

`String output ="Welcome to the All-Stars Summit Registration Site, Canada";`

It should be,

`var output ="Welcome to the All-Stars Summit Registration Site, Canada";`

Check [javaScript Strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String)

And also `setTimeout(setDateChange(), timeTillNextDate)` should be `setTimeout(setDateChange, timeTillNextDate)`

Final js code looks like,

```
document.onload = setDateChange();

            function setDateChange(){
                // datestring format yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss
                var output ="Welcome to the All-Stars Summit Registration Site, Canada";
                if (new Date().getTime() > (new Date("2015-07-15 23:59:00").getTime()))
                    {
                        output ="The All-Stars Summit Registration Site, Canada, is now closed";
                    }
            document.getElementById('header').innerHTML = output; //change the html/text inside of the span with the id closed'.
            }

        setDateChange();

        //figure out which date is next
        //*********************
        var timeTillNextDate = (new Date("2015-07-15 23:59:00")).getTime();
        var timeTillRun = (new Date("2015-07-15 23:59:00")).getTime() - (new Date()).getTime();
        if(timeTillRun > 0){
            setTimeout(setDateChange, timeTillNextDate);  //have occured.
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please replace all the `Date()` with:

```
(new Date())
```

As most of the functions work on the `object` than the `class`. Example:

```
var timeTillNextDate = (new Date("2015-07-15 23:59:00")).getTime();
var timeTillRun = (new Date("2015-07-15 23:59:00")).getTime() - (new Date()).getTime();
```